# How do I reproduce the EXCEL function RATE in any programming language e.g. ruby?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, ruby

I need to be able to calculate the annual interest rate in the same way EXCEL does it in it's function called [RATE](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Rate-Function.html) However I cannot find the underlying math anywhere.

Preferably I would like to implement it in either ruby or python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Exonio library in Ruby:

https://github.com/Noverde/exonio

Like this:

`Exonio.rate(number_of_periods, payment_per_period, present_value)`

Answer (score 2):

## Python

[`numpy.rate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html#numpy.rate) computes the rate of interest per period.

```
rate(nper, pmt, pv, fv[, when, guess, tol, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example in *VBA*:

```
Function MyRATE(nper As Integer, pmt As Double, pv As Double, Optional fv As Double = 0, _
                              Optional PaymentEnd As Integer = 0, Optional guess As Double = 0.1)
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double ' coefficients of the equation
    Dim R As Double, RTmp As Double, i As Integer

    ' Initialize coefficients and R
    R = 1 + guess
    a = (pmt * (1 - PaymentEnd) - pv) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)
    b = (fv - pmt * PaymentEnd) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)
    c = (-pmt * (1 - PaymentEnd) - fv) / (pv + pmt * PaymentEnd)

    ' Iterate
    For i = 1 To 20
        RTmp = R - (R ^ (nper + 1) + a * R ^ nper + b * R + c) / ((nper + 1) * R ^ nper + a * nper * R ^ (nper - 1) + b)
        If Abs(RTmp - R) < 0.0000001 Then Exit For
        R = RTmp
    Next i

    If i <= 20 Then
        MyRATE = RTmp - 1
    Else
        MyRATE = "N/A" ' Must try another guess
    End If
End Function
```

To use the function *(in a worksheet cell)*:

[image]

PLease note both the minus sign on the third argument and the multiplication by 12.